# Product of digits

Tags: java

```
public class ProductOfDigits {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int x = Math.abs(n);
    int product = 1; 

        if (x >=0 && x<=9) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        else  {         
        product = product * (x % 10); 
        x = x/10;
        System.out.println(product);
        }
```

When the input is negative number, the product is between first and last digit. Can anyone explain? I have tried `Math.abs()` to get absolute value but it is impossible and it is killing me now.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing that in a loop? Or a recursive? Or any other method of repetition?

Comment: well, the exercise doesnt require a loop for it. It only tests 1 number at a time but i didnt quite understand when the number has more than 2 digits, the product is only between 1st and 3rd, 4th etc...

Comment: How are you intending to sum more than 2 digits without repetition???

Comment: i am  really new to Java, can you explain more in details? Our teacher never did this, its compulsory for programming students but he never explains to us.

Comment: @TrungĐỗ I've answered your question. It's a solution without loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.log10()` function from java to get the number of your digits and then calculate the first digit based on it:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    if (number < 0) {
        number *= (-1);
    }

    int digits = (int) Math.log10(number);
    int lastDigit = number % 10;
    int firstDigit = (int) (number / Math.pow(10, digits));

    int product = lastDigit * firstDigit;
    System.out.println(product);
}
```

And of course, if your number is negative, you can use `Math.abs()` (instead of `if`)

Comment: Why should 256 return 60 ? I know it's 2*5*6, but `the product is between first and last digit` tells me that the actual result should be 12. And yes, I know I didn't use `Math.abs()`, I wanted to give the OP another solution.

Comment: Still questionable. But thank you for your observation :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductOfDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int x = Math.abs(n);
        int ç = 1;
        int product = 1;
        if (x == 0) {
            product = 0;
        } else {
            while (x > 0) {
                product *= x % 10;
                x /= 10;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

**Sample run-1:**

```
Enter an integer: -256
60
```

**Sample run-2:**

```
Enter an integer: 0
0
```

**Sample run-3:**

```
Enter an integer: 9
9
```

**Sample run-4:**

```
Enter an integer: 256
60
```

**Recursive version:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductOfDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(productOfDigits(n));
    }

    static int productOfDigits(int n) {
        n = Math.abs(n);
        if (n > 0 && n < 10) {
            return n;
        }
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (n % 10) * productOfDigits(n / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: its so simple yet i couldnt figure out. Thank you so much

Comment: but 0  to 9 doesnt work.. anything with 1 digit doesnt work..

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductOfDigits {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
  int n = input.nextInt();
  int x = Math.abs(n);
  int product = 1; 
    
   if (x >=0 && x<=9) {
    System.out.println(x);
   }
   else  {
     while (x > 0) {
            product *= x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }
        System.out.println(product);
   }
 }
}
     this works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your current code only prints out the last digit of the entered integer because you are only doing `product = product * (x % 10);` (can be simplified to `product *= x % 10;`) and `x = x / 10;` (can be simplified to `x /= 10;`) once each. You should repeatedly do these two operations until `x` is 0.

You could use a for loop or a while loop for this. Here's how to write this with a for loop:

```
for (; x > 0 ; x /= 10) {
    product *= x % 10;
}
```

The condition for the `if` statement can also be changed to just `x == 0`, as the `x` values 1-9 can all be correctly handled by the `else` clause.